# ng-model values not being captured when generated by php function

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, angular-ngmodel

So I have a function that generates honeypot form fields in Laravel.

The issue is when I submit the form with Angular, the javascript object doesn't contain the my_time or my_name fields.

```
public function generate(array $honey_name, array $honey_time)
{
    $honey_time_encrypted = parent::getEncryptedTime();
    // Encrypt the current time

    $html = '<div id="' . $honey_name['name'] . '_wrap" style="display:none;">' .
                '<input type="text" ' . $this->attributes($honey_name) . ' id="' . $honey_name['name'] . '" />' .
                '<input type="text" ' . $this->attributes($honey_time) . ' value="' . $honey_time_encrypted . '" />' .
            '</div>';

    echo $html;
}
```

Any thoughts why?

**UPDATE:**

Blade Template

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm(formData)">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name', 'ng-model' => 'formData.name']) !!}
        {!! Honeypot::generate(['name' => 'my_name', 'ng-model' => 'formData.my_name'], ['name' => 'my_time', 'ng-model' => 'formData.my_time']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email', 'ng-model' => 'formData.email']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        {!! Form::text('subject', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Subject','ng-model' => 'formData.subject']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '5', 'placeholder' => 'Message', 'ng-model' => 'formData.message']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-default center-block']) !!}
    </div>
</form>
```

**Submitted form data:**

```
$scope.submitForm = function(formData) {
    console.log(formData);
    Contact.submit(formData).then(function(results) {
        SweetAlert.swal({
            title: "Success!",
            text: "Thanks for getting in touch! I usually respond within 12 hours.",
            type: "success",
        });
    });
};


// Output of console.log();
Object {name: "Daniel", email: "abc@123.com", subject: "asdsadsafas fasfaf", message: "asjfasf aalhfsfa flaskfh aklsflakf a"}
```

So it's missing the `my_time` and `my_name` models, which causes validation to fail.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't detect my form fields"? Can you post the exact output of that function? Just to be sure of the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Angular doesn't post empty form fields, so that was part of the problem.

The second issue had to do with `formData.my_time`. If you plan to set the input value server side, then you must use `ng-init="foo = 'bar'" ng-model="foo"`.

So once I added `ng-init="formData.my_time = \'' . $honey_time_encrypted . '\'"` I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `<form>` element.

Try it this way:

```
$html = '<div id="' . $honey_name['name'] . '_wrap" style="display:none;">' .
'<form method="post" action="some action here">' .
'<input type="text" ' . $this->attributes($honey_name) . ' id="' . $honey_name['name'] . '" />' .
'<input type="text" ' . $this->attributes($honey_time) . ' value="' . $honey_time_encrypted . '" />' .
'</form></div>';
```

Comment: No, that's not it. See my update, which offers a fuller context.